# Convert NSString to NSDictionary bug

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I have a string from server, and when i try to convert it to `NSDictionary` - i get "`nil`". When i try to write same `NSString` by myself - it's ok!

I get from server encoded string, then i use "AES256DecryptWithKey" from NSString+AESCrypt.h to decrypt, and get NSString, this string i convert to NSData and then try to get NSDictionary

```
NSString *str = @"{\"error\":{\"password\":[\"Error wrong!\"]}}"; //string written by myself

NSData *jsonData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];
```

This code work, but then i get this string from server - not(

NSData log (message from server) - <7b226572 726f7222 3a7b2270 61737377 6f726422 3a5b22d0 9dd0b5d0 bfd180d0 b0d0b2d0 b8d0bbd1 8cd0bdd1 8bd0b920 656d6169 6c20d0b8 d0bbd0b8 20d0bfd0 b0d180d0 bed0bbd1 8c225d7d 7d000000>

NSData log (my string) - <7b226572 726f7222 3a7b2270 61737377 6f726422 3a5b22d0 9dd0b5d0 bfd180d0 b0d0b2d0 b8d0bbd1 8cd0bdd1 8bd0b920 656d6169 6c20d0b8 d0bbd0b8 20d0bfd0 b0d180d0 bed0bbd1 8c225d7d 7d>

If i NSLog string from server, it - {"error":{"password":["Error wrong!"]}} , string without "\"

Then i "po &error.localizedDescription" - 
error: address of property expression requested
error: 1 errors parsing expression

Then i "po error.localizedDescription" - Printing description of error:
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.) UserInfo=0x7f9940497550 {NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

What it can be??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says:

> Garbage at end.

So, comparing your data and the data from the server, we see:

```
Test string data:
<7b226572 726f7222 3a7b2270 61737377
 6f726422 3a5b22d0 9dd0b5d0 bfd180d0
 b0d0b2d0 b8d0bbd1 8cd0bdd1 8bd0b920
 656d6169 6c20d0b8 d0bbd0b8 20d0bfd0
 b0d180d0 bed0bbd1 8c225d7d 7d>

Server data:
<7b226572 726f7222 3a7b2270 61737377
 6f726422 3a5b22d0 9dd0b5d0 bfd180d0
 b0d0b2d0 b8d0bbd1 8cd0bdd1 8bd0b920
 656d6169 6c20d0b8 d0bbd0b8 20d0bfd0
 b0d180d0 bed0bbd1 8c225d7d 7d000000>
```

The decoded data is 3 bytes longer. Maybe it is padded ahead of the encryption or as an effect of your decryption due to some padding parameter. As a workaround you could remove the stray `000000`.

Comment: How i can remove this 000000 ?

Comment: `[NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] - 3]`

Comment: You better don't insert it in the first place. :)

Comment: Yes, until someone fixes the code with the superfluous null-terminators.

Comment: If the server side is using mcrypt don't worry, there will be no fix, the bozos who created mcrypt decided to use null padding which is non-standard and not to support PKCS#7 padding. It is even noted by the developers that the padding will fail if the data has a trailing 0x00 byte--nioce touch. The correct answer to this is to add PKCS#7 padding prior to calling the encryption function and to replace the PKCS#7 padding with 0x00 bytes prior to calling the crypt decryption function.